# How do I set boolean variables in v-card for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
data: () => ({
    show: false,

    prices: [
      {title: '£500', info: 'eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus', show: false},
      {title: '£1000', info: 'eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus'},
      {title: '£1500', info: 'eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus'},
      {title: '£2000', info: 'eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus'}
    ]
  })
```

```html
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="show" temporary absolute color="grey">
    <v-card v-for="price in prices" v-bind:key="price" height="250" fluid style="margin-bottom: 30px" >
      <v-card-title class="justify-center">{{price.title}}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text class="justify-center">{{price.info}}</v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
      <v-btn outlined class="justify-center" v-on:click="`${price.show}`" >enquire</v-btn>
      
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card> 
    
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

This is what I have tried so far, and it doesnt seem to work. I'm trying to get a navigation drawer feature 4 cards, and once you click the button for one of those cards, another navigation drawer opens/full page overlay card with the data from the specific card.

Comment: All your `prices` objects should have a `show` property in order for it to be reactive. Also, what exactly is `v-on:click="\`${price.show}\`"` meant to be? What do you want to happen when you click?

Comment: I guess v-on:click property expects a function or expression, not a boolean. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: On click, I want another overlay to pop-up, so lets just say another <v-card> to pop up in the center of the screen. Is there any way to do this with a function or boolean?